# grunt responsive-images-extender doesn't process img tags

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I have a very basic Gruntfile.js (because I'm just trying to get responsive-images-extender to work),

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

    require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);
    var config = grunt.file.readYAML('Gruntconfig.yml');

    grunt.initConfig({
        responsive_images_extender:{
            target: {
                options: {},
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    src: ['index.{html/htm/php}'],
                    cwd: 'src/',
                    dest: 'dist/'
                }]
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', ['responsive_images_extender']);
}
```

in my `src/index.html` I have one image, just to test this plugin.

```
<body>
     <img alt="this is an awesome image" src="awesome.jpg" class="test">
</body>
```

When I run grunt, it doesn't process any `img` tags, why is this?

```
simon@EDELWEISS:~/Udacity/Portfolio$ grunt
Running "responsive_images_extender:target" (responsive_images_extender) task
>> Processed 0 <img> tags

Done.
```

Comment: What is your folder structure? It sounds as if the task isn't even checking your `index` file. Also, `src: ['index.{html/htm/php}']` looks wrong, shouldn't it be `src: ['index.{html,htm,php}']`?

Comment: It "works" indeed when I change the / to colons. although I get another error, `Running "responsive_images_extender:target" (responsive_images_extender) task
Warning: Object #<Object> has no method 'isAbsolute' Use --force to continue.` Any idea what that means?

Comment: No, but googling around I see that this grunt task won't work if your version of node is < 0.10. See this: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector/issues/686#issuecomment-113925284

Comment: Mine is v0.10.37
I wonder if it could be an issue that my grunt is version 1.0.1 rather than the dependency of 0.4.5

Comment: The version of grunt doesn't matter. You should update your version of node.https://nodejs.org/en/download/

Comment: Thanks mparnisari, we're one step further. Now I get `Path must be a string. Received [ 'src/index.html' ]`. Is my path wrong? The `Gruntfile.js` is located in `~/someproject/` and the index in `~/someproject/src/`

Comment: @sjbuysse: were you able to make this work? I tried downgrading node with nvmw, but I haven't been able to make it work either. or did you find another plugin that works like responsive images extender? Thanks!